# How to call methods of template types in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How to call methods of template types in C++11?

Example:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
    // How to call a method here like t.method()?
}
```

Is this possible in C++11 somehow to first check if T has that method,
and if it does then to use it?

Comment: Just call `t.method()`

Answer (score 6):

C++ templates gain much of their power (and devious error messages) from their lack of constraints. You can think of templates as being "copy and pasted" by the compiler for every different type that they are invoked with (except, unlike the preprocessor, the compiler actually knows what a type is and doesn't muck around with literal string replacement).

Simply call the method assuming it exists, and if the user passes in a type that does not have that method, a compiler error will be generated.

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
    t.method();      // Generates error unless `method` really is a member of T
}
```

This also lets code like this work:

```
template <typename T>
void less(T const& a, T const& b) { return a < b; }

assert(less(1, 2));    // Works as expected

struct NonComparable { };
less(NonComparable(), NonComparable());   // Error
```

Comment: Wow this is possilbe?! I thought it can't be so I did not even try it.

Comment: @user: Yep :-) It's as if you did it with a real type, except that the code for that type is generated on the fly by the compiler as needed instead of being hard-coded to one type. C++ templates are fun!

Comment: The beatiful thing is you get compile and not run-time error! Amazing!

Comment: @user3111311, It gets better. For example, you can have the function choose another based on whether the type has that member function or not ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe088dffffbea85f)).

Comment: @user3111311 If you like this, I highly suggest googling for template meta-programming and/or looking at boost enable_if and boost mpl. Templates are incredibly powerful once you figure out how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the Boost [Type Traits Introspection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/) library.